# MarketingCloudSDK (5.2.1) iOS: duplicate symbol ___llvm_profile_runtime

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios

I have just integrated the MarketingCloudSDK (5.2.1) via CocoaPods to an iOS app and I am facing a duplicate symbol error. Someone already had the same issue posted to the apple forum:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/105532 but never got a reply.

All our pods are statically linked. The App is pure Objective C. We added for the App "Other Linker Flags": -all_load for good reasons (which is actually causing the trouble).

In our app we have "Code coverage" set to "Gather coverage" for all targets. If I turn it off, it is working, but our CI should really run with code coverage.

Is it possible that the sdk was build with CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE? I believe it is the corresponding flag.

Or some other profiling flags, i.e. -fprofile-instr-generate which would be rejected by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1964/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

@theguy we are aware of this issue and the conflict presented by the "-all_load" linker flag in conjunction with CocoaPods.

We are determining the best path forward with the change to the SDK.

In the meantime, is it possible to switch to -force_load with a specific path to the output of the pod's build (the .a)? This may address the problem directly while we work out the SDK change.